# How does bycrypt.compare() function of NodeJS work internally?

Tags: node.js, bcrypt, password-hash

How does bycrypt.compare() work when comparing the input password and the hashed password stored in database?

1. Does it take the hashed password from the database, decrypts it and then compares it with the plaintext password?
   *OR*
2. Does it hash the plaintext password which is taken as an input and keeps on hashing it as per saltrounds till it matches the stored hashed value in database?

I have tried looking up in the official documentation of bycrypt package by NodeJS [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt), but there is no detail description about its internal working. It would be very helpful if someone can shed some light on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It can't be 1 - the hashed password is not encrypted, it's hashed.  You can't get back to the plaintext password that generated it.

Comment: 2. Also, it doesn't hash until match is found as the number of required hashes is known.